# Automatically "Capture CC payment" when confirming shipments

Tags: acumatica

I have been asked the question by one of my customers that they would like to automatically "Capture CC Payment" for Sales orders at the time that the shipper is confirmed.

I know that in Acumatica, there is the batch processing methods to handle doing this in bulk but they'd still like to have it automatically do it as mentioned above.

My initial thoughts were a Customization that will use an Automation Step when the shipper is confirmed to load the order and execute the "Capture CC Payment" step.

More or less a customization step that is composed of
1) A custom method in the shipper screen that loads the order(s) in question and then executes the "Capture CC Payment" button/function
2) An automation step assigned to the shipper at the time of confirmation that executes the above method.

Is this the best way of handling this request or is there another pre-existing method that I might have overlooked?

The customer is currently on 4.20.2115 with no real interest in going to 5.1 anytime soon.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have a hummer in your hands, everything is a nail :). I can propose you solution from C# prospective. As a solution, I propose you to override method confirm in extension class with usage of delegate. I don't know about which form you are talking about, but lets assume, that form has graph SubmitterManager. Lets also assume, that you want to track method CreatePayment, which has paramethers string, IDictionary, IDictionary. Then you can create graph extension SubmitterManagerExt, and use PXOverride attribute with delegate in the following way:

```
public class SubmitterManagerExt : PXGraphExtension<SubmitterManager>
{
    [PXOverride]
    public bool CreatePayment(string viewName,
    IDictionary keys,
    IDictionary values,
    Func<string, IDictionary,
    IDictionary, bool> method)
    {
        // Call your method CreatePayment
        bool result = method(viewName, keys, values);
        if(result)
            {
                // here you can add some C# code, which will do something 
                // with created payments
             }
    }
    return result;
    }
}
```